# webpack HMR not loading changes

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

I'm developing a simple, static HTML website. Right now, there's just one html file, index.html. Using Webpack 3.10.0. I have HMR configured.

When I make changes to one of my stylesheets, it recompiles and reloads as expected:

```
[WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
client?5cf9:222 [WDS] App hot update...
log.js:23 [HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
log.js:23 [HMR] Updated modules:
log.js:15 [HMR]  - ./src/styles/app.scss
log.js:23 [HMR] App is up to date.
```

But when I make changes to the index.html the chrome console says it's recompiling, but at the end of the recompile it says 'nothing hot updated':

```
[WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
client?5cf9:222 [WDS] App hot update...
log.js:23 [HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
log.js:23 [HMR] Nothing hot updated.
log.js:23 [HMR] App is up to date.
```

I'm using seperate dev & prod webpack config files, with a common being merged in to each.  Here's common:

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const FaviconsWebpackPlugin = require('favicons-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/js/index.js'
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        hot: true
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.[hash].js',
        // path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
              test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
              use: [
                  {
                      loader: 'file-loader',
                      options: {
                          name: '[name].[ext]'
                          // outputPath: 'img/',
                          // publicPath: 'img/'
                      }
                  }
                  ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: ['html-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(s*)css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: {
                        plugins: function() {
                            return [
                                require('precss'),
                                require('autoprefixer')
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }, 'sass-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            hash: true,
            title: 'Thinkpiece Partners',
            template: 'src/html/index.html',
            inject: 'body'
        }),
        new FaviconsWebpackPlugin({
            // Your source logo
            logo: './src/img/icon/icon-1024.png',
            // The prefix for all image files (might be a folder or a name)
            prefix: 'icons-[hash]/',
            // Emit all stats of the generated icons
            emitStats: true,
            // The name of the json containing all favicon information
            statsFilename: 'iconstats-[hash].json',
            // Generate a cache file with control hashes and
            // don't rebuild the favicons until those hashes change
            persistentCache: true,
            // Inject the html into the html-webpack-plugin
            inject: true,
            // favicon background color (see https://github.com/haydenbleasel/favicons#usage)
            background: '#fff',
            // favicon app title (see https://github.com/haydenbleasel/favicons#usage)
            title: 'Thinkpiece Partners',

            // which icons should be generated (see https://github.com/haydenbleasel/favicons#usage)
            icons: {
                android: true,
                appleIcon: true,
                appleStartup: true,
                coast: false,
                favicons: true,
                firefox: true,
                opengraph: false,
                twitter: false,
                yandex: false,
                windows: false
            }
        })
    ]
}
```

and dev...

```
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        port: 8000
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I got it solved by adding your currently HTML path rather then dist build.

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: './path/html/files'
    watchContentBase: true,
},
```